# Bad layout with both lettrine module and builtin initals in two column setup in ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv, lettrine, drop-cap

I am seeing broken positioning of letters produced by the `lettrine` module. Here is my MVE:

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\usemodule[lettrine]

\definehead[recipe][section]
\setuphead[recipe][
  beforesection={\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumns}]

\definenumber[stepnum][way=bytext,prefix=no]

\definestartstop[steps][
  before={\startsubsubsubject[title={Příprava}]\setnumber[stepnum]{1}},
  after={\stopsubsubsubject}]

\definestartstop[step][
  before={\lettrine[Lines=3]{\getnumber[stepnum]}{}},
  after={\incrementnumber[stepnum]}]

\starttext
\startrecipe[title={Bábovka}, reference={babovka}]
  \startsteps
    \startstep
      A word word word word.
    \stopstep

    \startstep
      Another word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word.
    \stopstep

    \startstep
      Yet another word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word.
    \stopstep
  \stopsteps
\stoprecipe

\stoptext
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image: Lettrine problem]

Can I fix it anyhow or is this the `lettrine` module problem?

---

**UPDATE**

The `\setnumber[stepnum]{1}` in the source should be `\setnumber[stepnum][1]`. But this does not fix the problem.

---

**UPDATE 2**

While using `\placeinitial` works better, it still has some problems in the two column layout:

[image: Imgur]

Please notice the **2** and the extra vertical space at the beginning of the second column. Here is my updated MVE:

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\usemodule[lettrine]

\definehead[recipe][section]
\setuphead[recipe][
  beforesection={\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumns}]

\definenumber[stepnum][way=bytext,prefix=no]

\definestartstop[steps][
  before={\startsubsubsubject[title={\bf Příprava}]\setnumber[stepnum][1]},
  after={\stopsubsubsubject}]

\definestartstop[step][
  before={\lettrine[Lines=2]{\getnumber[stepnum]}{}},
  after={\incrementnumber[stepnum]}]

\setupinitial[font=Regular sa 2.5,distance=1pt,state=start,n=2]

\definestartstop[xstep][
  before={\placeinitial {\getnumber[stepnum]}{}},
  after={\incrementnumber[stepnum]}]

\starttext
\startrecipe[title={Bábovka}, reference={babovka}]
  A word word word word. A word word word word. A word word word
  word. A word word word word. A word word word word. A word word word
  word. A word word word word. A word word word word.

  \startsteps
    \startxstep
      A word word word word.
    \stopxstep

    \startxstep
      Another word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word.
    \stopxstep

    \startxstep
      Yet another word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word word word word word word
      word word word word word word word word.
    \stopxstep
  \stopsteps
\stoprecipe

\stoptext
```

Comment: @Aditya: Thanks, using `\setupinitial`/`\placeinitial` it works a lot better.

Comment: Change `before={\testpage[3]\placeinitial {\getnumber[stepnum]}}}` The `\testpage[3]` macro will cause a page break if there are less than 3 lines on the current page. (Not sure if it works well with columns).

Comment: @Aditya: Using `\testpage[3]` does not seem to do anything for the test case.